# How to compare 3 tables and merge their columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d857c/2)

These are my tables;

```
         mysql> show tables;
         +--------------------+
         | Tables_in_products |
         +--------------------+
         | main_info          |
         | product1           |
         | product2           |
         +--------------------+
         3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is my first table

```
         mysql> select * from main_info; 
         +------+------+-------+-------+----------+
         | key1 | key2 | info1 | info2 | date     |
         +------+------+-------+-------+----------+
         | 1    | 1    | 15    | 90    | 20120501 |
         | 1    | 2    | 14    | 92    | 20120601 |
         | 1    | 3    | 15    | 82    | 20120801 |
         | 2    | 1    | 17    | 90    | 20130302 |
         | 2    | 2    | 16    | 88    | 20130601 |
         +------+------+-------+-------+----------+
         5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is product table1 :

```
         mysql> select * from product1;
         +------+------+--------+--------------+
         | key1 | key2 | serial | product_data |
         +------+------+--------+--------------+
         | 1    | 1    | 0      | 15.556       |
         | 1    | 1    | 1      | 14.996       |
         | 1    | 1    | 2      | 12.556       |
         | 1    | 1    | 3      | 15.669       |
         | 1    | 2    | 0      | 12.556       |
         | 1    | 2    | 1      | 13.335       |
         | 1    | 3    | 1      | 12.225       |
         | 1    | 3    | 2      | 13.556       |
         | 1    | 3    | 3      | 14.556       |
         | 2    | 1    | 0      | 12.556       |
         | 2    | 1    | 1      | 13.553       |
         | 2    | 1    | 2      | 12.335       |
         +------+------+--------+--------------+
         12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is second product table

```
         mysql> select * from product2;
         +------+------+--------+--------------+
         | key1 | key2 | serial | product_data |
         +------+------+--------+--------------+
         | 1    | 1    | 0      | 5.556        |
         | 1    | 1    | 1      | 4.996        |
         | 1    | 2    | 0      | 2.556        |
         | 1    | 2    | 1      | 3.335        |
         | 1    | 2    | 2      | 2.56         |
         | 1    | 2    | 3      | 3.556        |
         | 1    | 3    | 1      | 2.225        |
         | 1    | 3    | 2      | 3.556        |
         | 2    | 2    | 0      | 2.556        |
         | 2    | 2    | 1      | 3.553        |
         +------+------+--------+--------------+
         10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have more than 8 product table, in which I would like to compare `key1, key2 and serial`, of 2 product table and main_info table, depending on the maximum I would like to merge, if product data is not exist then substitute `NaN` and finally would like to have 1 output like below

***Expected O/P***

```
   key1       key2       serial     info1      info2      date       product_table1_data product_table2_data
   1          1          0          15         90         20120501   15.556     5.556     
   1          1          1          15         90         20120501   14.996     4.996     
   1          1          2          15         90         20120501   12.556     NaN       
   1          1          3          15         90         20120501   15.669     NaN       
   1          2          0          14         92         20120601   12.556     2.556     
   1          2          1          14         92         20120601   13.335     3.335     
   1          2          2          14         92         20120601   NaN        2.56      
   1          2          3          14         92         20120601   NaN        3.556     
   1          3          1          15         82         20120801   12.225     2.225     
   1          3          2          15         82         20120801   13.556     3.556     
   1          3          3          15         82         20120801   14.556     NaN       
   2          1          0          17         90         20130302   12.556     NaN       
   2          1          1          17         90         20130302   13.553     NaN       
   2          1          2          17         90         20130302   12.335     NaN       
   2          2          0          16         88         20130601   NaN        2.556     
   2          2          1          16         88         20130601   NaN        3.553
```

Kindly someone help me to get expected result

**This is structure of my database;**

```
 $ cat product.sql
   --
   -- Table structure for table `main_info`
   --

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `main_info`;

   CREATE TABLE `main_info` (
     `key1` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `key2` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `info1` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `info2` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `date` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


   LOCK TABLES `main_info` WRITE;

   INSERT INTO `main_info` VALUES ('1','1','15','90','20120501'),('1','2','14','92','20120601'),('1','3','15','82','20120801'),('2','1','17','90','20130302'),('2','2','16','88','20130601');
   UNLOCK TABLES;


   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product1`;

   CREATE TABLE `product1` (
     `key1` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `key2` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `serial` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `product_data` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


   LOCK TABLES `product1` WRITE;

   INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES ('1','1','0','15.556'),('1','1','1','14.996'),('1','1','2','12.556'),('1','1','3','15.669'),('1','2','0','12.556'),('1','2','1','13.335'),('1','3','1','12.225'),('1','3','2','13.556'),('1','3','3','14.556'),('2','1','0','12.556'),('2','1','1','13.553'),('2','1','2','12.335');

   UNLOCK TABLES;



   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product2`;

   CREATE TABLE `product2` (
     `key1` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `key2` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `serial` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
     `product_data` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


   LOCK TABLES `product2` WRITE;

   INSERT INTO `product2` VALUES ('1','1','0','5.556'),('1','1','1','4.996'),('1','2','0','2.556'),('1','2','1','3.335'),('1','2','2','2.56'),('1','2','3','3.556'),('1','3','1','2.225'),('1','3','2','3.556'),('2','2','0','2.556'),('2','2','1','3.553');
   UNLOCK TABLES;
```

**I tried this, but this is not taking care about serial maximum for each key pair and about NaN**

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM main_info INNER JOIN product1
 ON 
 main_info.key1=product1.key1 and
 main_info.key2=product1.key2
 INNER JOIN product2 
 ON 
 product1.key1=product2.key1 and
 product1.key2=product2.key2
```

***Merging process detail : Answer for comment***

1 . take key1 and key2 from main_info table
2 . search in table product1, product2, if key1 and key2 is found in any one of the table or in both the table, get the length of serial column for those keys, find maximum length,

for example in product1 table, we have 4 serial number

```
     +------+------+--------+--------------+
     | key1 | key2 | serial | product_data |
     +------+------+--------+--------------+
     | 1    | 1    | 0      | 15.556       |
     | 1    | 1    | 1      | 14.996       |
     | 1    | 1    | 2      | 12.556       |
     | 1    | 1    | 3      | 15.669       |
```

and in second table we have just 2 serial numbers, 0 and 1 only

```
     +------+------+--------+--------------+
     | key1 | key2 | serial | product_data |
     +------+------+--------+--------------+
     | 1    | 1    | 0      | 5.556        |
     | 1    | 1    | 1      | 4.996        |
```

so merge serial numbers from both the table and check whether data exists or not if exists then keep product_date else write NaN

Output should be like this when you merge 2 product tables, once this is done add info1 info2 and date column corresponding to key1 and key2

```
     +------+------+--------+--------------+--------------
     | key1 | key2 | serial | product_data |product_data2
     +------+------+--------+--------------+-------------
     | 1    | 1    | 0      | 15.556       |5.556
     | 1    | 1    | 1      | 14.996       |4.996
     | 1    | 1    | 2      | 12.556       |NaN
     | 1    | 1    | 3      | 15.669       |NaN
```

Please let me know if you need more information

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? Give us some code we won't make the whole code for you.

Comment: @user3637224 Please describe your merging process in more detail.

Comment: Full join can be helpful here. Try to achieve desired result with that.

Comment: @fancyPants : Thanks for reply updated original post

Comment: SELECT x.*,y.product_data2 FROM product1 x LEFT JOIN product2 ON y.key1 = x.key 1 AND y.key2 = x.key2 AND y.serial = x.serial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select T.key1,T.key2,T.serial,T.info1,T.info2,T.date,p1.product_data,p2.product_data
from
(SELECT m.key1 as key1,m.key2 as  key2,m.info1 as info1,m.info2 as info2 ,m.date as     date,p1.serial as serial  
from main_info as m
join product1 as p1 on m.key1=p1.key1 and m.key2=p1.key2 
union
SELECT m.key1 as key1,m.key2 as  key2,m.info1 as info1,m.info2 as info2 ,m.date as     date,p2.serial as serial  
from main_info as m
join product2 as p2 on m.key1=p2.key1 and m.key2=p2.key2 
) as T
left join product1 as p1 on T.key1=p1.key1 and T.key2=p1.key2 and p1.serial=T.serial
left join product2 as p2 on T.key1=p2.key1 and T.key2=p2.key2 and p2.serial=T.serial
```

**Edit**
or

```
select T.key1,T.key2,T.serial,m.info1,m.info2,m.date,p1.product_data,p2.product_data
from
(SELECT p1.key1 as key1 ,p1.key2 as key2 ,p1.serial as serial  
from product1 as p1
union
SELECT p2.key1 as key1,p2.key2 as key2,p2.serial as serial  
from product2 as p2 
) as T
left join product1 as p1 on T.key1=p1.key1 and T.key2=p1.key2 and p1.serial=T.serial
left join product2 as p2 on T.key1=p2.key1 and T.key2=p2.key2 and p2.serial=T.serial
left join main_info as m on T.key1=m.key1 and T.key2=m.key2
```

Comment: +1 Your code is working, I am interested to put "NaN" and I have 8 tables actually ...after union is it necessary to select main_info table every time ? can't we simplify this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT  * FROM ( SELECT main_info.* ,
 product1.product_data as product_table1_data,
 IF(product2.product_data IS NULL,"NaaN", 
 product2.product_data)  as product_table2_data, product1.serial 
 FROM product1 
 LEFT JOIN product2 ON product1.key1 = product2.key1 
 AND product1.key2 = product2.key2 
 AND product1.serial=product2.serial 
 INNER JOIN main_info on 
 main_info.key1=product1.key1 and 
 main_info.key2=product1.key2 

 UNION 

 SELECT main_info.* , 
 IF(product1.product_data IS NULL,"NaaN",product1.product_data) as product_table1_data,
 product2.product_data  as product_table2_data, 
 product2.serial 
 FROM product1 RIGHT JOIN product2 ON product1.key1 = product2.key1 
 AND product1.key2 = product2.key2 
 AND product1.serial=product2.serial 
 INNER JOIN main_info on 
 main_info.key1=product2.key1 and 
 main_info.key2=product2.key2) AS TEMP ORDER BY TEMP.key1,TEMP.key2,TEMP.serial
```